# How to store user information to access in another dialog - Bot framework V3

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I am facing a problem storing user profile in bot framework. With my bot I am using AAD authentication and storing the retrieved username in class

```
tokenstring = resultToken.AccessToken;
userName = resultToken.UserName;
Globalvariables.username = userName;
```

And try retrieving in another dialog something like`Globalvariables.username`
but when two users accessing the bot simultaneously it is messing up completely. Is there an alternate way to do this?

I am using Bot framework v3 .

Below is another way I tried to get the information.

In Sign In dialog

```
StateClient stateClient = new StateClient(new MicrosoftAppCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"]));
BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(authContext.Activity.ChannelId, authContext.Activity.From.Id);
userData.SetProperty<string>("username", resultToken.UserName);
```

For retriving the stored user name in another Dialog

```
StateClient stateClient = new StateClient(new MicrosoftAppCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"]));
BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(context.Activity.ChannelId, context.Activity.From.Id);
context.UserData.SetValue("username", userData.GetProperty<string>("username"));
```

But this seems depreciated and not working as expected .

Comment: Use a dictionary with username as key and tokenstring as value

Comment: But to access it in the other dialog I need to have the username available, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the **StateClient** methods are deprecated because they use the default state service which has been deprecated.  However, the **IDialogContext** has **IDataBag** implementations that enable easy access for storing and retrieving information in .UserData, .PrivateConversationData and .ConversationData

within SignIn dialog you should be able to store the Username via the **IDialogContext** like:

```
context.UserData.SetValue("UserName", resultToken.UserName);
```

Then access it within other dialogs:

```
var userName = context.UserData.GetValueOrDefault("UserName", string.Empty);
```